# Weird conflicting implementation in rust

Tags: rust, traits

I'm making a tiny GUI library in Rust for practice. Minimal reproducible example of my problem is as follows:

```rust
/// Trait for rendering engines
pub trait Renderer { /* ... */ }

pub trait Element<Win: Renderer> {
    fn paint(&self);
    fn width(&self) -> u32;
    fn height(&self) -> u32;
}

/// "Composed" element is element, that consists of multiple sub-elements, eg. button consists of frame and laconveniences a covinience trait, because implementing `Element` directly might be cumbersome.
pub trait ElComposed<Win: Renderer> {
    /// Returns the top-level subelement of self
    fn main_el(&self) -> Box<dyn Element<Win>>;
}

impl<T: ElComposed<Win>, Win: Renderer> Element<Win> for T {
    fn paint(&self) { self.main_el().paint() }
    fn width(&self) -> u32 { self.main_el().width() }
    fn height(&self) -> u32 { self.main_el().height() }
}

/// Element displaying just a circle
pub struct Circle;

/// Implementing `Element` trait directly on `Circle`
impl<Win: Renderer> Element<Win> for Circle {
    fn paint(&self) { todo!() }
    fn width(&self) -> u32 { todo!() }
    fn height(&self) -> u32 { todo!() }
}
```

[Link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=67a3aadb04d696e67f9c49bddbd859ea)

Because `Element` trait contains quite a few methods, it may be time-consuming to implement directly, so, as you can see in the code, I added the `ElComposed` convenience trait to make it easier to implement for elements consisting of multiple sub-elements (eg. button consists of a frame and label).

But now, when I implement the `Element` trait directly (`impl<Win: Renderer> Element<Win> for Circle` in the code above), the code doesn't compile:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `Element<_>` for type `Circle`
   |
21 | impl<T: ElComposed<Win>, Win: Renderer> Element<Win> for T {
   | ---------------------------------------------------------- first implementation here
...
31 | impl<Win: Renderer> Element<Win> for Circle {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ conflicting implementation for `Circle`
   |
   = note: downstream crates may implement trait `ElComposed<_>` for type `Circle`
```

But downstream crates *cannot* implement trait `ElComposed` for `Circle`, because both traits are in my crate. So why does this error occur and how can I fix it?

Comment: I think you may be thinking about this from too much of a C++/Java perspective. To me, it seems like `ElComposed` isn't really a trait at all. It could be more accurately written as `struct ElComposed { mainElement: Box<dyn Element<Win>> }`, and *that* structure can have a concrete implementation of whatever you want. If you really need it to be a trait, you'll need to use the [newtype pattern](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/patterns/patterns/behavioural/newtype.html) to get the `Element` impl, rather than a blanket impl.

Comment: Thanks, @SilvioMayolo. But let's say I want to implement a button. With your approach, I would need to instantiate the `ElComposed` struct and specify inner layout _for each button in my app_ (which would be a lot of bloat) to make the buttons display each different text.

The point is, that the return value of `main_el` has to be able to change based on fields of the struct (such as the text on button) `ElComposed` is implemented on

Comment: *"But downstream crates cannot implement trait `ElComposed` for `Circle`"* - you are mistaken. `ElComposed` is generic and that type parameter could be a local type. A downstream crate with `MyRenderer` could implement `Renderer` for `MyRenderer` and implement `ElComposed<MyRenderer>` for `Circle`.

Comment: Good read if you are trying to build a UI/Rendering engine: https://www.warp.dev/blog/why-is-building-a-ui-in-rust-so-hard
This explains why UI design in Rust is hard, and how to work around it.